# Unable to load hive table with fixed width file using SerDe

Tags: hive, fixed-width, hive-serde

I have fixed width file having 5 fixed width column. Here is the structure of the file. `{col1:3char, col2:35char, col3:3char, col4:11char, col5:4char}`. Here is the sample file

```
111  SagarKhatavkar                     030       9999ABIT

112  VishalKataria                      028       9999ABIT

113  GauravSomvanshi                    032       9999ABIT

114  SonalKartekiya                     029       9999ABIT
```

So as suggested in other posts I use RegEx. Here is the DDL I created.

```
CREATE TABLE emp (emplid STRING, name STRING, age String, salary String, dept STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
     "input.regex" = "(.{4})(.{35})(.{3})(.{11})(.{4})", 
     "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s"
     )
```

After using load from local to load the data in this table gives all values as NULL.

```
load data local inpath '/home/test1/emp.txt' into table emp;

Running select on the table
hive> select * from emp;

OK

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

Time taken: 0.959 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

Please advise what's wrong with the DDL? I am using 2.4.2.0-258 version of Hive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. There was an issue with first column data. The file supposed to have EXACT 57 bytes. Otherwise it would mark the complete row as NULL.